# Using Babylon.js with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, game-development, babylonjs

Can I use babylon.js with electron to build a desktop game with HTML5, Js and WebGL? If it is possible, it is a good help if you have a demonstration. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/webgl - A good example for THREE.js - think that adapt Babylon is not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

For example of babylon integration into electron project look [here](https://github.com/b52/electron-es6-react). Just ignore the react integration parts and combine it with @stdob-- recommendation.